# "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings" asking for StorageBlobContributor access for non-vnet Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rbac

I am deploying SQL Server via ARM template. While setting Audit settings for this sql server with Storage Account, it is asking for permissions.

As per the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/audit-write-storage-account-behind-vnet-firewall#prerequisites) we need the permissions, ONLY when the storage account is behind a Firewall. However, my storage account is open to internet, so the permission pre-requisite should not apply here.

I have used Powershell cmdlet 'Set-AzSqlServerAudit' to set this configuration, and it works. But this fails in the ARM template.

Template snippet:

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "isDevopsAuditEnabled": false,
                "retentionDays": 0,
                "auditActionsAndGroups": [
                    "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
                    "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
                    "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP"
                ],
                "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false,
                "isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled": false,
                "state": "Enabled",
                "storageEndpoint": "[parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccount')]",
                "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccountSubscriptionId')]"
            }
        },
```

Error:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 4:37:56 AM - Resource Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings 'coe-extollo-apis-sqlserver-dev/Default' failed with message '{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "BlobAuditingInsufficientStorageAccountPermissions",
        "message": "Insufficient read or write permissions on storage account 'xtocoeeucommonsdev'. Add permissions to the server Identity to the storage account."
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, you do not add `storageAccountAccessKey` in your template then the SQL server has no permissions to access the storage account. If you do not add it, you need to enable identity on Azure SQL server and assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the identity on storage account level. Then the SQL can have permissions to access the storage account. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/auditingsettings?tabs=json).
[image]

So please update your template as below.

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('serverName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "isDevopsAuditEnabled": false,
                "retentionDays": 0,
                "auditActionsAndGroups": [
                    "SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
                    "FAILED_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP",
                    "BATCH_COMPLETED_GROUP"
                ],
                "isStorageSecondaryKeyInUse": false,
                "isAzureMonitorTargetEnabled": false,
                "state": "Enabled",
                "storageEndpoint": "[parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccount')]",
                "storageAccountAccessKey":"<account key>"
                "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[parameters('centralMonitoringStorageAccountSubscriptionId')]"
            }
        },
```