# unable to assign rbac role via code using bicep fails with Insufficient read or write permissions on storage account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-bicep

Got a storage account in a different subscription and resource group, trying to use bicep to assign rbac roles and so far the results are somewhat confusing.

assign_role.bicep

```
param storageAccountName string
param principalId string
  @allowed([
      'Device'
      'ForeignGroup'
      'Group'
      'ServicePrincipal'
      'User'
      ''
  ])
param principalType string = ''
@allowed([
    'Storage Blob Data Contributor'
    'Storage Blob Data Reader'
])
param roleDefinition string

var roles = {
    // See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles for these mappings and more.
    'Storage Blob Data Contributor': '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe'
    'Storage Blob Data Reader': '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1'
}

var roleDefinitionId = roles[roleDefinition]

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' existing = {
    name: storageAccountName
}

resource roleAuthorization 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
    // Generate a unique but deterministic resource name
    name: guid('storage-rbac', storageAccount.id, resourceGroup().id, principalId, roleDefinitionId)
    scope: storageAccount
    properties: {
        principalId: principalId
        roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
        principalType: empty(principalType) ? null : principalType
    }
}
```

From main.bicep

```
module roleAuthorization './modules/assign_sa_role.bicep' = {
  name: 'roleAuthorization'
  scope: resourceGroup('my-sub','my-rg')
  params: {
      principalId: '6bcedc96-f01a-41a4-9c62xxxxxxxx' 
      principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
      storageAccountName: 'xxxxx'
      roleDefinition: 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'
  }
  dependsOn:[CreateManagedIdentity,CreateSQLAudit]
}
```

Here is what happens, in the above example I have hard coded the principal ID, I still get the error below.

`"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"BlobAuditingInsufficientStorageAccountPermissions","message":"Insufficient read or write permissions on storage account 'my_storage_account'. Add permissions to the server Identity to the storage account."}]}]}]}]}}`

If I then go onto the portal to manually add the role assignment to the principal and the code is executed a second time I get the error below.

`At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"RoleAssignmentExists","message":"The role assignment already exists."}]}]}]}}`

Makes me wonder, what is going on here ?
If I use the output of a resource, its no different.

`identityIDs[0].properties.principalId`

Not sure what is wrong here or how to assign roles correctly via bicep modules.

Comment: you r first erro is because you ve already created the role assignment, delete it let the bicep runs again

Answer (score 0):

> "BlobAuditingInsufficientStorageAccountPermissions", "message": "Insufficient read or write permissions on storage account 'my_storage_account'. Add permissions to the server Identity to the storage account.

According to this **[SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811329/microsoft-sql-servers-auditingsettings-asking-for-storageblobcontributor-acces)** by Jim Xu, that error occurs because the server identity does not have sufficient permissions to access the storage account.

Either you need to pass the `storageAccountAccessKey` or enable identity on Azure SQL server and assign `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to the identity on the storage account level.

> "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.", "details": [{"code": "RoleAssignmentExists", "message": "The role assignment already exists."}]}}]}}

I agree with Thomas's comment; the above line indicates that the role assignment is already assigned. If you need to reassign, delete and reassign to the storage account using bicep.

In my environment, I tried the same code below with identity to assign **`rbac`** role.

**Code:**

```
param sname string = 'testvenkatmi'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource sample 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2022-01-31-preview' = {
  name: sname
  location: location
}

module roleAuthorization './assign_role.bicep' = {
  name: 'roleAuthorization'
  scope: resourceGroup('<subid>', '<resource grp name>')
  params: {
      principalId: sample.properties.principalId
      principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
      storageAccountName: 'venkat678'
      roleDefinition: 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/servers/auditingsettings?tabs=json&pivots=deployment-language-bicep)

Answer (score 0):

I have just test it, it works, this circumstance is about across subsription deployment. you login in sub1 and deploy role assignment to sub2, your account should be the following permissions:

1. deployment in sub1
2. `owner` in sub2 or the storage account resource.

I have copy your code and make some finely modify

`assign_sa_role.bicep`

```
param storageAccountName string
param principalId string
@allowed([
    'Device'
    'ForeignGroup'
    'Group'
    'ServicePrincipal'
    'User'
    ''
])
param principalType string = ''
@allowed([
    'Storage Blob Data Contributor'
    'Storage Blob Data Reader'
])
param roleDefinition string

var roles = {
    // See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles for these mappings and more.
    'Storage Blob Data Contributor': '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/ba92f5b4-2d11-453d-a403-e96b0029c9fe'
    'Storage Blob Data Reader': '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/2a2b9908-6ea1-4ae2-8e65-a410df84e7d1'
}

var roleDefinitionId = roles[roleDefinition]

resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-06-01' existing = {
    name: storageAccountName
}

resource roleAuthorization 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
    // Generate a unique but deterministic resource name
    name: guid('storage-rbac', storageAccount.id, resourceGroup().id, principalId, roleDefinitionId)
    scope: storageAccount
    properties: {
        principalId: principalId
        roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId
        principalType: empty(principalType) ? null : principalType
    }
}
```

`main.bicep`

```
param otherSubscriptionId string = 'sub2 subid'
param otherResourceGroupName string = 'sub2 rg'
param storageAccountName string = 'xx'
param principalid string = 'xxx'

module roleAuthorization './modules/assign_sa_role.bicep' = {
  name: 'roleAuthorization'
  scope: resourceGroup(otherSubscriptionId, otherResourceGroupName)
  params: {
      principalId: principalid
      principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
      storageAccountName: storageAccountName
      roleDefinition: 'Storage Blob Data Contributor'
  }
}
```

`deploy.ps1`

```
## you should log into sub1
$rgName = "sub1 rg"

$templateFile = "main.bicep"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment `
  -Name 'wbtestacrosssubscription' `
  -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
  -TemplateFile $templateFile
```